# Does the giant octorok exist?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Near Zora's Domain are several stone slabs that tell the history of the Zora. One of them tells of a time that Prince Sidon fought a giant octorok:

> Prince Sidon's Great Escape
>
> There was once a giant Octorok in Hateno Bay, large as a mountain, which terrorized the village's fishers. Hearing of their distress, Prince Sidon went forth to personally eliminate the offending Octorok. But this Octorok was a tricky beast.
>
> After the prince dodged one of the stones it spat, it inhaled him whole. Such had been the fate of many strong warriors who went to slay the Octorok. Not one had come back alive. Just as it seemed Prince Sidon would be counted among them, the giant Octorok twisted in pain. The tip of a silverscale spear pierced the Octorok's stomach from within, revealing itself as the source of the beast's agony.
>
> Incredibly, Prince Sidon had fought his way out by stabbing his spear over and over into the monster's stomach. Unable to bear the pain, the Octorok coughed up the prince and scrambled to escape. Ever since, the fishers of Hateno Bay have passed down this heroic tale: The Prince Who Slew the Fell Octorok.

After I found this, I went to Hateno Bay, looking forward to fighting a giant Octorok. I have not been able to find any such monster, however.

Is this tale just purely for world-building lore? Most of the tablets are, but at least one gives you a real hint about an actual treasure, so this could be meant as a real hint as well. Has anyone seen this octorok?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is purely world building - there is no Giant Octorok in the game.

Or at least, the official game guide does not list one anywhere, as a potential enemy or otherwise.

Comment: Truth.  However, it's worth noting that DLC is a thing, so it may yet appear in the future ;)

Comment: What's the source for this information?

Comment: @GendoIkari Hardcover game guide, which lists all potential enemies and bosses, as well as their stats.

Comment: That information should probably be included to make a good answer. Of course you can't quote anything in the guide stating that something doesn't exist, but saying that the guide lists all enemies and doesn't mention that one would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a Giant Octorok in Breath of the Wild. I base this on the lack of mention in any of the wikis of such an enemy - notably nothing [here](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Enemies_in_Breath_of_the_Wild), [here](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Breath_of_the_Wild_Enemies), or [here](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Monsters).

Interestingly (though this is purely my speculation), this could be a reference to an enemy from another Zelda game - the [Big Octorok](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Octorok) in [The Legend of Zelda: The Minish Cap](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_The_Minish_Cap). While the descriptions of the enemies seem similar, this would necessarily imply that Link is in fact Prince Sidon - something currently unsubstantiated, and likely a discussion beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: The problem with that theory is that the octorok is only big because link is extremely small.  It's not really likely to be the same thing.

Comment: @JMac I agree, hence it being my own, unsupported speculation

Comment: Alternatively, link kills it and Prince Sidon takes credit for the kill.

Comment: If it's a reference to anything, I would guess it refers to the Big Octos from Wind Waker.